# How to scrape data from a target server without node-exporter or cadvisor

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, cadvisor

I have three URL's that need to be monitored. I do not have access to the servers in which they're running. So, I cannot install node exporter or cadvisor like I usually do. Is there a way to expose and scrape metrics using just the URL? (P.S - I'm not picky about what data I can scrape)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do  you mean you don't have access to the servers? Your Prometheus server doesn't see them or you cannot login to the servers?

Comment: I do not have the IP addresses, @rcarba

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about if the URL is reachable (and dont want to know anything about the server behind that URL), you can use the [prometheus blackbox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter). That can be installed anywhere and just probes that the url is reachable (and gives some details about the http request).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jens Baitinger. Blackbox exporter worked for me

Comment: If you this post solved your problem you should validate the answer.